# Processing C command line arguments

Tags: c, parsing, command-line, parameters, package-managers

How do I process multiple command line arguments like say in a package manager? I am giving a shot at writing a package manager and right now accepting the packages to install is giving me quite the headache. For example the user wants to install package x,y and z. Right now my code will send 3 different requests to a function. I would like to get all the package names in one go. So for example, the user wants to install package x,y and z, it would be processed and my code will send a request to a function stating that it needs x,y and z and the function will begin work immediately.

Here's my current implementation...

```
case 'S':
    switch (argv[1][2]) {
        case 'u':
            id = 1;
            alfred("system", "update", "", id);
            break;

        case 'r':
            id = 1;
            alfred("system", "reload", "", id);
            break;

        case 'i':
            if (argc - 2 != 0) {
                // Loop until packages are complete.
                packages = 2; // Starting point of packages = argv[2][0]
                srand(time(NULL)); // Seed for random number
                id = rand(); // Generate random number for id
                argc = argc - 2 + 1; // argc minus the number of packages and plus 1
                /* This is a very inefficent loop! */
                /* Must get all targets and feed it to alfred */
                while (packages <= argc) {
                    alfred("system", "install", &argv[packages][0], id);
                    packages++;
                }
            } else {
                printf("Unrecognized format. Execute alfred -h for more information.\n");
            }
            break;

        default:
            printf("Unrecognized format. Execute alfred -h for more information.\n");
            break;
    }
    break;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can also try [libargtable](http://argtable.sourceforge.net/).
I used it before to parse various arguments, it's very handy.

Answer (score 0):

Have you try the getopt library?

http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Getopt.html

Comment: Yeap tried it already... Didn't fit my needs unfortunately... Thanks anyway! :D

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are looking for is [getopt](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/getopt.3.html)

the documentation says

**The  getopt() function parses the command-line arguments**.  Its arguments argc and argv are the argument count and
       array as passed to the main() function on program invocation.  An element of argv that starts with  '-'  (and  is
       not  exactly  "-" or "--") is an option element.  The characters of this element (aside from the initial '-') are
       option characters.  If getopt() is called repeatedly, it returns successively each of the option characters  from
       each of the option elements.

Comment: I already tried getopt. It didn't fit my needs as I needed -- options. For example for --force-yes... Thanks anyway! :)